# How to know if a binary has been linked with "pie" linker flag?

Tags: gcc, linker

I would like to know if a binary has been linked using Position independent executable flag during linking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and link non-PIE:

```
$ gcc -Wall -c main.c
$ gcc -Wall -no-pie main.o
```

See the program headers (my `^^^^^^^^^`-annotations):

```
$ readelf -l a.out 

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 
Entry point 0x400400
            ^^^^^^^^
            | Absolute entry point
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R      0x8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                       | Absolute load address      
                 0x00000000000006c8 0x00000000000006c8  R E    0x200000
  LOAD           0x0000000000000e10 0x0000000000600e10 0x0000000000600e10
                 0x0000000000000220 0x0000000000000228  RW     0x200000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000000e20 0x0000000000600e20 0x0000000000600e20
                 0x00000000000001d0 0x00000000000001d0  RW     0x8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000400254 0x0000000000400254
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x000000000000058c 0x000000000040058c 0x000000000040058c
                 0x000000000000003c 0x000000000000003c  R      0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000000e10 0x0000000000600e10 0x0000000000600e10
                 0x00000000000001f0 0x00000000000001f0  R      0x1
  ...
  ...
```

Compile and link PIE:

```
$ gcc -Wall -fPIC -c main.c
$ gcc -Wall -pie main.o
```

See the program headers again:

```
$ readelf -l a.out 

Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Entry point 0x530
            ^^^^^
            | Offset from unknown load address
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R      0x8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000000238
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                       | Unknown load address
                 0x0000000000000830 0x0000000000000830  R E    0x200000
  LOAD           0x0000000000000db8 0x0000000000200db8 0x0000000000200db8
                 0x0000000000000258 0x0000000000000260  RW     0x200000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000000dc8 0x0000000000200dc8 0x0000000000200dc8
                 0x00000000000001f0 0x00000000000001f0  RW     0x8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000000254
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x00000000000006ec 0x00000000000006ec 0x00000000000006ec
                 0x000000000000003c 0x000000000000003c  R      0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000000db8 0x0000000000200db8 0x0000000000200db8
                 0x0000000000000248 0x0000000000000248  R      0x1
```